# Scaling a plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph with pyplot. The graph is quite big, so in order to not only see many overlapping dots indicating the nodes, I have to scale the output picture.

I used:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
zoom=30
w, h = f.get_size_inches()
f.set_size_inches(w * zoom, h * zoom)
```

But now I have the problem, that I have big white spaces at the edges of the picture. There nothing is drawn and it is caused because the picture is much higher than wide.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: White spaces are due to the padding set. You can use `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, bottom=0.05, top=0.95)` and play with the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of zooming a figure, you can use `figsize` argument to `plt.subplots`. You might also be interested in [`plt.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

So you can do something like:

```py
f,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))  # figure size in inches
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.tight_layout()  # fill empty space
```

I also removed `1,1` from call to `subplots` as it's not necessary when you make only one plot.

Comment: I used to work with figsize. The problem was, that I was not able to keep the proportions of the figure (as I could not figure them out)